# Find maximum sum of subarray with length less than or equal to k in Python

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given n= 8, pn/ = [2, 5, -7, 8, -6, 4, 1, -9], k= 5. We can select the subarray [2, 5, -7, 8] with sum = 8 and size 4 which is less than k= 5.Hence, the answer is 8. It can be shown that the answer cannot be greater than 8.

Comment: I see what looks like a homework assignment, but I don't see a question. What are you having trouble with? Have you tried anything so far? We may be able to help you with a specific problem you are having, but we will not do your homework for you. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Well, I have tried to write code in python using kadane's algorithm but it seems getting wrong answer, am I allowed to ask this kind of questions here because I am not well aware about this

Answer (score 0):

Solvable with a deque in `O(n)`. Approximate code, not tested and definitely missing some edge cases, but presents the right idea:

```
deque = []
s = prefix sums of p, s[i] = p[0] + p[1] + ... + p[i]
for i = 0, n:
    if not deque.empty and i - deque.first > k + 1: # otherwise we would have subarrays longer than k (s[a] - s[b] gives the sum pf p[b+1]+...+s[a])
        deque.pop_first()
    while not deque.empty and s[i] < s[ deque.last ]: # otherwise our queue wouldn't be sorted anymore
        deque.pop_last()
    if s[i] - s[ deque.first ] > global_max:
         global_max = s[i] - s[ deque.first ]
    deque.push_last(i)
```

The idea is to use the deque to store the index of the minimum prefix sum for the last `k` positions. That one will contribute to the maximum possible subarray for the current position, and it will be the first in the deque. We keep the deque sorted to make sure that the first element is always the minimum.

Because each element can enter and leave the deque at most once, even if we use nested loops, the complexity is linear.